# Change all href tags to lower case

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string that contains multiple href tags such as:

href="HTTPS://www.example.com" and href="hTtp://www.example.com"

I need to change it to lower case, example:

href="https://www.example.com" and href="http://www.example.com"

what do I need to do with the code below to achieve it:

```
Dim strRegex As String = "<?href\s*=\s*[""'].+?[""'][^>]*?"
Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(StringThatContainsHrefTags)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            Dim pattern As String
            pattern = "http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?"
            If Regex.IsMatch(myMatch.ToString(), pattern) Then
            'what do I do here?    
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What is the complete string? If you parse HTML use a HTML-Parser

Comment: The string is entered by users from an online html editor so the string will be different every time

Comment: It is not `<href..` but `<a href=` (or something like `<a target="_blank" href="..`). Do you also want to lowercase "WWW.example.com" and "example.com/PATH"?

Comment: @Craig: Then show the complete html-string that the user entered or was created from the editor. Especially because it will be a different HTML string you sould consider to use a real csv parser instead of regex hacks.

Comment: the www part onwards does not matter that much as long as I can change the https and http parts to lower case

Comment: @TimSchmelter, that is not really an option at this stage. I need to follow the regex route or something similar to change all https and http parts to lower case

Comment: @Craig: why that's not an option? Click "manage nuget packages" install HtmlAgilityPack, write 2-3 lines of code and you're finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this if you do not want to parse the HTML content.

```
Dim Input As String = "something <a href=""hTTpS://xxx"">asdf</a> and then <a href=""HttP://xxx"">asdf</a>"
Dim Output As String = Regex.Replace(Input, "<a\s+[^>]*href=""(?<Protocol>https?):", New MatchEvaluator(Function(X) X.Value.ToLower), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This will handle only the HTTP/HTTPS part. You can extend the regex to entire URL and perform other validations from your code if needed.
There's shortcut in the code expecting only one pair of braces in the regex. Otherwise some tunning in X.Groups("Protocol").Value would be needed.